# Django - Update a Model every couple of minutes

Tags: django, rest, django-models

I am building an app, where I need to fetch some data from an API and update all the models with that data every few minutes.

What would be a clean way to accomplish something like this?

Comment: Write a management command and schedule it using cron or similar.

Comment: management command + [celery beat](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) as cron scheduler

Comment: If that is what you need to need to do, you might thoroughly check if your architecture is best. I'd consider querying the API on demand and caching results in-memory either using django's caching system or a varnish or sth similar.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I fear hammering the API with too many requests in this case. But I'll look into the caching system, thanks!

Comment: @Rechunk It should be less, since you don't query it if you don't have to, and if you have cached results, you are not hitting it either.. Or do query some bulk endpoint and get all data in one request and think of only getting single records on demand?

Comment: @schwobaseggl I basically need to load social media stats. Might it be better to do Webscraping in that case? I thought about doing one scrape every few minutes, store the results in the database and just load them from there when the user requests them. But please let me know if you'd have a cleaner approach in mind.

Comment: @Rechunk If there is an API, use it. To me, your plan sounds like you want to use the database as a cache and fill that cache eagerly. That feels like not using the proper tools for the task. A database can store stuff permanently and there are better caching tools out there. These tools allow you to very simply set a cache timeout and take care of not serving stale content.

Comment: @schwobaseggl yes, I was hesitant about the database. I'll look into the API's and the django caching system, thanks for the recommendations!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156727/discussion-between-schwobaseggl-and-rechunk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's a quite open question.

You'll need to create a task that runs every few minutes, you can do this with Celery. Celery has a task schedluer http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html wich will launch a certain function at a configured time similar to a crontab

The task then would fetch the data, http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ is a very good library to make http requests.

And lastly but no less important you would need to serialize the fetched data and save it to your model. Django rest framework serializing capabilities are a great starting point, but if data structure is simple enough you can just use JSON python library json.loads(data) and create a function that translate the fields on the API to the fields of the model.

By the way, I'm supposing a REST API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a task management tool that has the feature of running periodic tasks in the intervals you specify, like [Periodic Tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) in [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

Also, If you run your code on a Unix-like system, you can stick with the core django functionality. Just write your functionality as a [Django Management Command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/) and set a [cronjob](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) to run it in your preferred interval.